# Project location not in inetpub\wwwroot

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7

If the website's physical directory is not in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and is instead in `C:\MyProjects\Project1` - which account needs what rights to the MyProjects or the Project1 folder?

I get a security error when I browse to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually the group `YOURMACHINE\IIS_IUSRS` which contains all the default app pool users. If you're using a domain user for the app pool then it'll be that instead.

They'll need at least read and list folder contents - and I expect Read & Execute too although I'm not 100%. I usually leave that on as it's in the default set of read permissions. If you have a SQL Express database in the tree then presumably they'll need permission to write to that too, etc.